# Select all nodes between two elements excluding unnecessary element from the intersection using XPath

Tags: xpath, scrapy

There’s a document structured as follows:

```
<div class="document">

    <div class="title">
        <AAA/>
    </div class="title">

    <div class="lead">
        <BBB/>
    </div class="lead">

    <div class="photo">
        <CCC/>
    </div class="photo"> 

    <div class="text">
    <!-- tags in text sections can vary. they can be `div` or `p` or anything. -->
        <DDD>
            <EEE/>
            <DDD/>
            <CCC/>
            <FFF/>
                <FFF>
                    <GGG/>
                </FFF>
        </DDD>
    </div class="text">

    <div class="more_text">
        <DDD>
        <EEE/>
            <DDD/>
            <CCC/>
            <FFF/>
                <FFF>
                    <GGG/>
                </FFF>
        </DDD>
    </div class="more_text">

    <div class="other_stuff">
        <DDD/>
    </div class="other_stuff">

</div class="document">
```

**The task is to grab all the elements between `<div class="lead">` and `<div class="other_stuff">` except the `<div class="photo">` element.**

The Kayessian method for node-set intersection `$ns1[count(.|$ns2) = count($ns2)]` works perfectly. After substituting `$ns1` with `//*[@class="lead"]/following::*` and `$ns2` with `//*[@class="other_stuff"]/preceding::*`,
the working code looks like this:

```
//*[@class="lead"]/following::*[count(. | //*[@class="other_stuff"]/preceding::*)
= count(//*[@class="other_stuff"]/preceding::*)]/text()
```

It selects everything between `<div class="lead"`> and `<div class="other_stuff">` *including* the `<div class="photo">` element. I tried several ways to insert `not()` selector in the formula itself

```
//*[@class="lead" and not(@class="photo ")]/following::*
//*[@class="lead"]/following::*[not(@class="photo ")]
//*[@class="lead"]/following::*[not(self::class="photo ")]
```

(the same things with `/preceding::*` part) but they don't work. It looks like this `not()` method is ignored – the `<div class="photo">` element remains in the selection.

***Question 1:*** **How to exclude the unnecessary element from this intersection?**

It’s not an option to select from `<div class="photo">` element excluding it automatically because in other documents it can appear in any position or doesn't appear at all.

***Question 2 (additional):*** **Is it OK to use `*` after `following::` and `preceding::` in this case?**

It initially selects everything up to the end and to the beginning of the whole document. Could it be better to specify the exact end point for the `following::` and `preceding::` ways? I tried `//*[@class="lead"]/following::[@class="other_stuff"]` but it doesn’t seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question 1: How to exclude the unnecessary element from this intersection?**

Adding another predicate, `[not(self::div[@class='photo'])]` in this case, to your working XPath should do. For this particular case, the entire XPath would look like this (formatted for readability) :

```
//*[@class="lead"]
 /following::*[
    count(. | //*[@class="other_stuff"]/preceding::*) 
        = 
    count(//*[@class="other_stuff"]/preceding::*)
 ][not(self::div[@class='photo'])]
/text()
```

> **Question 2 (additional): Is it OK to use * after following:: and preceding:: in this case?**

I'm not sure if it would be 'better', what I can tell is `following::[@class="other_stuff"]` is invalid expression. You need to mention the element to which the predicate will be applied, for example, 'any element' `following::*[@class="other_stuff"]`, or just 'div' `following::div[@class="other_stuff"]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In **Question 1** your code does really work but it still captures what is inside the `<div class="photo">` element. Specifically, it grabs `<CCC/>` as shown in the XPath Eval you kindly referenced to [http://xpatheval.apphb.com/pWdhFhupA](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/pWdhFhupA). 

Is there any way to totally exclude the `<div class="photo">` element with everything that is inside it? `//*` doesn’t help.

Comment: As to **Question 2**, I asked it just in case. Most of the answers to the questions about selecting elements between two specific nodes involve using the intersection method. However, if there’s a way to set the end element in such cases there might be no need to use the intersection. 

If I use the code `//*[@class="lead"]/following::div[@class="other_stuff"]` or `*` instead of `div` it selects the whole `<div class="other_stuff">` element for some reason but not the elements before.

Comment: @VladimirSirovitskiy replace `self::` axis with  `ancestor-or-self::` to exclude the `<div class="photo">` element and everything that is inside it : http://xpatheval.apphb.com/1cB98v629

Comment: This replacement is absolutely crucial. Now the code selects all the necessary elements and leaves out everything not needed. I’ve just tested it to exclude even more elements on the way simply by adding more arguments in the `not()` function using `| ` separator. It works just amazingly. Thanks a lot for your help!